# How to reset an auto-incremented value when another value changes?

Tags: postgresql

I'm actually working on a PostgreSQL DB structure and I'm having hard time figuring out how to solve a problem.
The DB will be recording data regarding architectural objects.
The main table, "object",have attributes that describe the object with information like *type*, *localization*, etc.
One of these attributes is a serial named *object_num*.
Another table is called "code" which contains a code made of three letters corresponding to the town where the mission is conducted.

Example :
I'm working on an architectural inventory for the city of Paris. The *code_name* will be PRS and the first entry (aka the first architectural entity : house, bridge, etc) will be associated to *object_num* 001.
So PRS001 will be a unique identifier referring to this specific architectural entity.
Things going on, I might end up with quite a few entries, for example entry PRS745.

Say this mission isn't finished yet but a new one starts for the city of Bordeaux, where BDX is going to identify the inventory. It would be great that the identifier for the first entry will be BDX001 rather than BDX746 (auto-increment).
Considering this, it will be also nice that, going back to the Paris mission after a few records for the Bordeaux mission (say BDX211), the next value will start back at (PRS)745 rather than (BDX)211.

So, is it possible to reset the value of a serial to 1 when using a new code ?
And is it possible to start back serial increment from the last value of a specific code ?

I guess you can perform this task with constraints and checks, but I'm not really familiar with these and am a bit lost...

Thanks for your help,

Yrkoutsk

Comment: Hi, Sorry, this is a bit unclear, can you rewrite the question with some code examples?  maybe post the schema? or high-level structure. Don't forget that when someone is reading your question - its his first time :)

Comment: Hi, ok, I thought regarding the question and my lack of knowledge, it would have been clearer to put it in full words....

Answer (score 0):

You could create separate sequences for each *code_name* and grab your auo-increment based on the *code_name*:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE PRS START 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE BDX START 1;

insert into your_table (object_num, code_name, other_data) 
                values ( code_name||lpad(nextval(code_name)::char,3,'0')
                       , code_name, other_data);
```

You will have to create a new sequence every time you add a new code_name otherwise the db will end up throwing an error when you try accessing the nonexistent sequence.

Comment: Hi, it looks like what i'm looking for ! I'll make some tests and come back to this thread after. Thank you